# How to use variable in another file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass an variable to another file. I use the `lat` variable in new js file but not working.

In address.php:

```
<div class="saveaddress">Click me</div>

<script>
    var lat;
    var lng;
    function displayLocation(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    } 
</script>
.
.
.
<script src="js/save.js"></script>
```

save.js file:

```
$('.saveaddress').click(function(){
    alert(lat);
}
```

How can I do that? (How can I do that? (I followed other questions but not worked for me.)

Comment: Did you try not redclaring `lat` and `lng`? Change `var lat = position.coords.latitude;` to  `lat = position.coords.latitude;` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try fixing the scope of the variable by not redclaring:

```
var lat;
var lng;
function displayLocation(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add the variable to the `window`:

```
function displayLocation(position) {
    window.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    window.lng = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Then:

```
$('.saveaddress').click(function(){
    alert(window.lat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the two var inside the displayLocation function